Using Socket.io with Flutter stream and BLoC pattern
I'm trying to learn BLoC pattern using flutter_bloc package in flutter. I'm aslo using socket_io_client package to connect to a local Node.js server.
I have 3 problems:

The first, when the state changes from connected (initial state) to disconnected, the "Disconnected" text doesn't persists on the screen, and it immediately goes to "Nothing".

Secondly, If the connection is severed between the app and Node.js, socket.io tries to reconnect. And when it succeeds, it never goes back to "Connected" again. Although I made another event to reconnect.

Thirdly, when the app (the client) emits a socket event to the server, to receive certain data (I see it in the terminal), the data is not displayed on the screen. Although the event is triggered.


Here's my code:
socket_screen.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import '../bloc/socket/socket.bloc.dart';
import '../model/active_layout.model.dart';


class SocketScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SocketScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
        title: const Text("Socket Test")
      ),
      body: BlocProvider<SocketBloc>(
        create: (BuildContext context) => SocketBloc()..add(const SocketConnectEvent()),
        child: BlocBuilder<SocketBloc, SocketState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is SocketConnectedState) {
              String message = state.message;
              return Center(
                child: Text(message)
              );
            }

            if (state is SocketDisconnectedState) {
              String message = state.message;
              return Center(
                child: Text(message)
              );
            }

            if (state is SocketOnReceiveState) {
              ActiveLayout data = state.data;
              return Center(
                child: Text(data.playlist.name)
              );
            }

            // if (state is SocketErrorState) {
            //   String message = state.error;
            //   return Center(
            //     child: Text(message)
            //   );
            // }

            return const Center(
              child: Text("Nothing")
            );
          }
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

socket.bloc.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart';
import '../../model/active_layout.model.dart';
part 'socket.event.dart';
part 'socket.state.dart';


const socketUri = "http://192.168.1.8:8000";
const uuid = "xyz";


class SocketBloc extends Bloc<SocketEvent, SocketState> {

  late Socket _socket;

  SocketBloc() : super(SocketInitialState()) {
    _socket = io(
      socketUri,
      OptionBuilder()
      .setTransports(['websocket'])
      .setQuery({ "uuid": uuid })
      .enableForceNewConnection()
      .build()
    );
    _socket.onConnect((_) => const SocketConnectEvent());
    _socket.onConnectError((data) => add(SocketConnectErrorEvent(message: data.toString())));
    _socket.onDisconnect((data) => add(SocketDisconnectEvent(message: data.toString())));
    _socket.onReconnectAttempt((data) => print("//////////////////// Reconnect Attempt $data"));
    _socket.onReconnectError((data) => print("//////////////////// Reconnect Error $data"));
    _socket.onReconnectFailed((data) => print("//////////////////// Reconnect Failed $data"));
    _socket.onReconnect((data) => SocketReConnectEvent());
    _socket.emit('join', { "uuid": uuid });
    _socket.on('playlist', (data) {
      // _activeLayoutStreamController.add(activeLayoutFromJson(data));
      print("//////////////////// Received Data $data");
      add(SocketOnReceiveEvent(data: data));
    });
    // _socket.onError((data) {
    //   print("//////////////////// Error $data");
    //   add(SocketErrorEvent(message: data.toString()));
    // });
    // _socket.on('joined', (data) => add(_SocketJoinedEvent.fromJson(data)));


    on<SocketConnectEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(SocketConnectedState("Connected"));
    });

    on<SocketConnectErrorEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(SocketConnectErrorState("Connection error"));
    });

    on<SocketReConnectEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(SocketConnectedState("Connected"));
    });

    on<SocketJoinEvent>((event, emit) {
      _socket.emit('join', { "uuid": uuid });
      emit(SocketJoinState("join"));
    });

    on<SocketJoinedEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(SocketJoinedState("joined"));
    });

    on<SocketOnReceiveEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(SocketOnReceiveState(event.data));
    });

    on<SocketDisconnectEvent>((event, emit) {
      // print("/////////////////////// event: ${event.message}");
      emit(SocketDisconnectedState("Disconnected"));
    });

    // on<SocketErrorEvent>((event, emit) {
    //   emit(SocketErrorState(event.message));
    // });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _socket.dispose();
    return super.close();
  }
}

socket.event.dart:
part of 'socket.bloc.dart';


@immutable
abstract class SocketEvent extends Equatable {
  const SocketEvent();
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class SocketConnectEvent extends SocketEvent {
  const SocketConnectEvent();
}

class SocketConnectErrorEvent extends SocketEvent {
  final String message;
  const SocketConnectErrorEvent({required this.message});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [message];
}

class SocketReConnectEvent extends SocketEvent {
  // const SocketReConnectEvent();
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}


class SocketJoinEvent extends SocketEvent {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class SocketJoinedEvent extends SocketEvent {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

// to receive playlist data
class SocketOnReceiveEvent extends SocketEvent {
  final ActiveLayout data;
  const SocketOnReceiveEvent({required this.data});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [data];
}

class SocketDisconnectEvent extends SocketEvent {
  final String message;
  const SocketDisconnectEvent({required this.message});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [message];
}

class SocketErrorEvent extends SocketEvent {
  final String message;
  const SocketErrorEvent({required this.message});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [message];
}

socket.state.dart:
part of 'socket.bloc.dart';


@immutable
abstract class SocketState extends Equatable {}

class SocketInitialState extends SocketState {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class SocketConnectErrorState extends SocketState {
  final String error;
  SocketConnectErrorState(this.error);
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [error];
}

class SocketConnectedState extends SocketState {
  final String message;
  SocketConnectedState(this.message);
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [message];
}

class SocketJoinState extends SocketState {
  final String message;
  SocketJoinState(this.message);
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [message];
}

class SocketJoinedState extends SocketState {
  final String message;
  SocketJoinedState(this.message);
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [message];
}

class SocketOnReceiveState extends SocketState {
  final ActiveLayout data;
  SocketOnReceiveState(this.data);
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [data];
}

class SocketDisconnectedState extends SocketState {
  final String message;
  SocketDisconnectedState(this.message);
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [message];
}

class SocketErrorState extends SocketState {
  final String error;
  SocketErrorState(this.error);
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [error];
}

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Try to use your events on BLoCListener, and check what happens

ok, thanks.. I'll try it.. but is everything else, regarding the code, is fine?

I can suggest you to use stateful widget instead stateless, probably it will solve your issue.

ok I'll try it.. but I have a question, and correct me if I'm wrong, I thought using state management like BLoC will enable you to use stateless widgets instead of stateful ones.. isn't this true?

Yes, you are right, probably problem in your code I suppose,  that problem in initialization, so try to use initState instead of create

got it.. thanks again.. you've been very helpful..

Does it works? Give feedback pls)

I'll try it, and I'll give you a feedback by tomorrow..
